# files not uploading to FTP Server

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, ftp

After the code has executed, its show me it has completed but the file has not been transferred to my FTP Server as far as i can see. 
 Any ideas on what i should try in order to get this task completed?

```
      Try
        Dim _UploadPath As String = "ftp://166.62.10.28/FileTransfer_Testing/updated.zip"
        Dim _FileName As String = "D:\update.zip"
        Dim _FTPUser As String = "shreay"
        Dim _FTPPass As String = "Abcd#1234"
        Dim _FileInfo As New System.IO.FileInfo(_FileName)

        ' Create FtpWebRequest object from the Uri provided
        Dim _FtpWebRequest As System.Net.FtpWebRequest = CType(System.Net.FtpWebRequest.Create(New Uri(_UploadPath)), System.Net.FtpWebRequest)

        ' Provide the WebPermission Credintials
        _FtpWebRequest.Credentials = New System.Net.NetworkCredential(_FTPUser, _FTPPass)

        ' By default KeepAlive is true, where the control connection is not closed
        ' after a command is executed.
        _FtpWebRequest.KeepAlive = False

        ' set timeout for 20 seconds
        _FtpWebRequest.Timeout = 200000

        ' Specify the command to be executed.
        _FtpWebRequest.Method = System.Net.WebRequestMethods.Ftp.UploadFile

        ' Specify the data transfer type.
        _FtpWebRequest.UseBinary = True

        ' Notify the server about the size of the uploaded file
        _FtpWebRequest.ContentLength = _FileInfo.Length

        ' The buffer size is set to 2kb
        Dim buffLength As Integer = 2048
        Dim buff(buffLength - 1) As Byte

        ' Opens a file stream (System.IO.FileStream) to read the file to be uploaded
        Dim _FileStream As System.IO.FileStream = _FileInfo.OpenRead()


        ' Stream to which the file to be upload is written
        Dim _Stream As System.IO.Stream = _FtpWebRequest.GetRequestStream()

        ' Read from the file stream 2kb at a time
        Dim contentLen As Integer = _FileStream.Read(buff, 0, buffLength)

        ' Till Stream content ends
        Do While contentLen <> 0
            ' Write Content from the file stream to the FTP Upload Stream
            _Stream.Write(buff, 0, contentLen)
            contentLen = _FileStream.Read(buff, 0, buffLength)
        Loop
        
        ' Close the file stream and the Request Stream
        _Stream.Close()
        _Stream.Dispose()
        _FileStream.Close()
        _FileStream.Dispose()

    ext.InnerText = "done..............."
    Catch ex As Exception
        ext.InnerText = "Error " + ex.Message
    End Try
```

Comment: Please edit your question carefully so that it is clear what is code and what not,

Comment: Basically you are missing a call to `_FtpWebRequest.GetResponse()`.

Comment: yes i got the file to ftp server actually i have duplicate file

Comment: make a time stamp for the files maybe?

Comment: So do you still have some problem or not?

Comment: Yes i got all file to ftp  Martin Prikry